# Highlighting included PDF

Tags: graphics, overlays, pdfpages, transparency

I use pdflatex on linux.

I would like to put a transparent colored box on top of an included PDF.
The goal is to highlight some line of the PDF.
The green box has to be transparent: I mean the white of the pdf becomes green and the black remains black.
Without background (see Test2 in the example) everything is fine. But the colored box cover the PDF completely.
I putted texts in my example, but at the end I need empty box *with a given size* highlighting a single line.

```
\documentclass[10pt,titlepage,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{pdfpages} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{transparent}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{xr-hyper} % multi-document ref
\usepackage[unicode,pdfpagelabels]{hyperref}
% 1pt = 035146 mm
\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
\includepdf[pages={8},%
  picturecommand={%
    \put(200,300){\pgfsetfillopacity{0.5}\colorbox{green}{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{Test1 Test1 Test1 Test1 Test1 Test1 Test1 Test1 Test1 Test1 }}}%
    \put(200,350){Test2 Test2 Test2 Test2 Test2 Test2 Test2 Test2 Test2 }
  }%
]{my.pdf}
\end{document}
```

The result for now is:
[image: pic]

**EDIT** After removing the transparent package:

[image]

Comment: I don't understand. What is the problem with your example?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The problem is that the green rectangle has completelly covered the PDF Text: "Chapter II: ...." To be correct it should be transparent (green but transparent)

Comment: I don't have your pdf, but with example-image-a4 (and slightly changed coordinates) it works fine. How are you compiling? What texsystem do you have?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I use pdflatex (no special option) with TexLive on Fedora. What is example-image-a4?

Comment: You are loading the transparent package. Try to remove it. Older version of the package were incompatible with tikz opacitiy.

Comment: example-image-a4 is a dummy picture in your tex system. You can use it for such examples.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Very good. Thank you. the transparent package is the problem! Now the text is gray instead of Black. I upload a new screen shot.

Comment: The `\pgfsetfillopacity` seems to be global somehow. You should add a `\pgfsetfillopacity{1.0}` for the text argument. Then I get black for it.

Comment: @MartinScharrer With opacity 1. the box is 100% covering, then I hide the pdf-text. That it: opacity 0.2: light green, light text in the box, dark PDF-text; opacity 0.8: dark green, dark  text in the box, light(gray) PDF-text;

Comment: The opacity is global and has to be reset to 1 at the end of the box. The solution is not exactly what I wanted, transparency, but it is about opacity. But it is good enough. Thank you all.

Comment: @PeptideChain: I meant adding a second `\pgfsetfillopacity` before `Test1 ...`, so that you switch back to full opacity for the text.

Comment: Alternative with `transparent` and `adjustbox` packages: `\adjustbox{minipage=\textwidth-2\fboxsep,bgcolor*=\transparent{.5}\color{green}}{Test1 Test1 Test1 Test1 Test1 Test1 Test1 Test1 Test1 Test1 }`. Works fine in my example.

Comment: @MartinScharrer. Then I have missed the meaning, but yes, it works as you say.